# Unable to parse JSON data properly in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my first time to convert JSON data with jQuery however, I get the following error when I try to convert the JSON string. Am I doing something wrong? I was searching for some simple sites about converting JSON string in jQuery, but most of the tutorial seems a bit difficult to understand. I would love to here some tips about converting jsons from url with jQuery if possible.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"result":[{"id":"25","name":"loplo\n","score":"1198"},{"id":"58","name":"adjm","score":"1131"},{"id":"60","name":"dragon with ","score":"1083"},{"id":"57","name":"tDj","score":"799"},{"id":"59","name":"dragon with ","score":"452"},{"id":"55","name":"Donny","score":"450"},{"id":"56","name":"ajo ","score":"401"},{"id":"61","name":"make ","score":"392"}]}' );
```

Error message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 35
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.m.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at leaderboard.js:16
```

Comment: Do you actually have that string literal in your JS code? If so, why? You could just do `var obj = {result: [{...`.

Comment: The `\n` in your string literal would be interpreted differently than if those two, real characters are in some JSON data. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve in the end?

Comment: \n character is breaking your json data. When you remove that, it parses just fine

Comment: I think this has been answered (newline needs to be escaped before the string is parsed), on an unrelated note I'd like to suggest you maybe use the built-in [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which has been supported since IE8, just in case you're unaware of its existence.

Comment: *"...about converting jsons from url with jQuery if possible"* What does ***"jsons from url"*** mean? You don't show any url in your question. You have a string literal of invalid JSON data embedded into your program, so we don't know if the issue you show is the actual issue.

Comment: Actually, I didn't want to post my json data from url, So I replaced it with just a string for sample. I was able to convert and json data to the string but was unable to handle it with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error message is the \n in the first element that has the name: "loplo\n"

This is because new lines are allowed in JSON objects like that as they need to be either removed or escaped.

To get around this you can do

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(mystring.replace(/\n/g,"\\n"));
```

You can read more about this here:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=616

Comment: Did you mean " new lines are [NOT] allowed in JSON"?

Comment: "New lines are not allowed in JSON"? Sure they are, they just need to be *escaped*.

Comment: fair enough they just need to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the new line character as the value of loplo:

> "loplo\n"
>   Remove the **\n** and it should work.

I don't recommend removing all of the \n with replace because you may want that. If you want to keep the \n, add a escape character before it, like this:

"loplo\\n" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```js
var e = '{"result":[{"id":"1351","identite":"RES ADDS","etat":"1","email":"udohou@gmail.com","telephone":"8787878","adresse":"COTONOU","nom_pays":"Togo","indicatif":"228"},{"id":"1350","identite":"MY DREAM","etat":"2","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"5248525","adresse":"COTONOU","nom_pays":"Togo","indicatif":"228"},{"id":"1349","identite":"UN ","etat":"1","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"66353364","adresse":"","nom_pays":"Benin","indicatif":"229"},{"id":"1348","identite":"DOHOU ULRICH SEMASSA &amp; Fils","etat":"1","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"66353364","adresse":"COTONOU","nom_pays":"Benin","indicatif":"229"},{"id":"1344","identite":"DC","etat":"2","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"66353364","adresse":"","nom_pays":"Afghanistan","indicatif":"93"},{"id":"1343","identite":"AGAIN","etat":"2","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"66353364","adresse":"","nom_pays":"Afghanistan","indicatif":"93"},{"id":"1342","identite":"SOCIAL LIMITED","etat":"3","email":"dohouulrich@gmail.com","telephone":"66353364","adresse":"","nom_pays":"Afghanistan","indicatif":"93"}]}';
var json = JSON.stringify(eval('(' + e + ')'));
var arr = $.parseJSON(json);
var resultData  = arr['result'] ;

console.log(resultData) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I changed the Json String data because yours was not working. I think it is not well formated

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also you could've just `const json = JSON.parse(e); const resultData = json.result`. The eval is entirely unnecessary, and extremely bad practice.